# How to run the prepared statement with arguments dynamically in a function?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I created `person` table, then inserted 2 rows into it as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  age INT
);

INSERT INTO person (id, name, age) 
VALUES (1, 'John', 27), (2, 'David', 32);
```

Then, I created the prepared statement `my_pre` with a [PREPARE statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html) which can update `age` with `id` in `person` table as shown below:

```sql
PREPARE my_pre(INT, INT) AS
  UPDATE person SET age = $1 WHERE id = $2;
```

Then, I created `my_func()` with the [EXECUTE statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) which has the `EXECUTE` statement to run `my_pre($1, $2)` dynamically as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(age INT, id INT) RETURNS VOID
AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'EXECUTE my_pre($1, $2)' USING age, id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But, calling `my_func()` got the error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func(45, 2);
ERROR:  there is no parameter $1
LINE 1: EXECUTE my_pre($1, $2)
                       ^
QUERY:  EXECUTE my_pre($1, $2)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function my_func(integer,integer) line 3 at EXECUTE
```

Actually, when I directly set `45` and `2` to `my_pre` in `my_func()` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS VOID
AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'EXECUTE my_pre(45, 2)';
END;                   -- ↑↑  ↑
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, I could call `my_func()` without error, then `age` of `David` was updated to `45` as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
 my_func
---------

(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT * FROM person;
 id | name  | age
----+-------+-----
  1 | John  |  27
  2 | David |  45
(2 rows)
```

Or, I created `my_func1()` which can update `age` with `id` in `person` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func1(age INT, id INT) RETURNS VOID
AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'UPDATE person SET age = $1 WHERE id = $2' USING age, id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, I created `my_func2()` with the `EXECUTE` statement which has the [SELECT statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) to call `my_func1($1, $2)` dynamically as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func2(age INT, id INT) RETURNS VOID
AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'SELECT my_func1($1, $2)' USING age, id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, I could call `my_func2()` without error, then `age` of `David` was updated to `45` as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func2(45, 2);
 my_func2
----------

(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT * FROM person;
 id | name  | age
----+-------+-----
  1 | John  |  27
  2 | David |  45
(2 rows)
```

So, how can I run the prepared statement `my_pre($1, $2)` dynamically in `my_func()`?

Comment: 1) Why are you using `EXECUTE my_pre()` in a function anyway? 2) Especially as per [plpgsql EXECUTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN): *The PL/pgSQL EXECUTE statement is not related to the EXECUTE SQL statement supported by the PostgreSQL server. The server's EXECUTE statement cannot be used directly within PL/pgSQL functions (and is not needed).*.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL prepared statements should not be executed from PL/pgSQL. Every embedded SQL is prepared by default. The `EXECUTE` command from PL/pgSQL is different command than SQL `EXECUTE` command (some other databases uses different access, but Postgres uses API similar to Oracle).

Unfortunately, SQL statement `EXECUTE` doesn't allow to use parameters (only `SELECT` and `CALL` statements allows parameters):

```
(2024-02-18 06:27:01) postgres=# execute x($1,$2) \bind 10 20 \g
ERROR:  08P01: bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0
LOCATION:  exec_bind_message, postgres.c:1716
```

So you cannot to pass parameters from PL/pgSQL `EXECUTE`. You can do it on query level by using `format` function:

```
EXECUTE format('execute x(%L, %L)', age, id);
```

This will be safe too.

The model for dynamic SQL is different than model used by some other databases. The reason is simple. PL/pgSQL statement does preparing and execution together, and then doesn't except so it will be call already prepared statement. Maybe the Oracle design is less messy, because they use syntax `EXECUTE IMMEDIATELY`, but it is too late to change it now. Today is possible to enhance SQL `EXECUTE` to support parametrization (the SQL statement `CALL` do this), but nobody wrote it (probably there is not too strong, too interesting use case).